# Glide's override is not shrinking image

Tags: android, android-glide

I have an image view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I have a pic show I use glide and the pic takes up the entire view as it should:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
   .load(path)
   .centerCrop()
   .into(iv);
```

However sometimes I don't have a picture and I just want to show an icon.  The icon is a resource.  I want the icon to be centered in the image view but I do not want the icon to take up the entire view (it will be way too big).  I am trying to use the override method to make the icon much small in the view.

Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
     .load(R.drawable.ic_picture_icon)
     .override(250, 250)
     .skipMemoryCache(true) // just for testing so it doesn't pull from cache
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE) // again just for testing
     .into(iv);

However I cannot get this to work.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  If so what am I doing wrong.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the ImageView layout_height and layout_width to wrap_content should solve the problem.